# Exception, with two references in base class with Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I had this problem in a project, since I don't want to give the whole domain scope, I've tried to simplify the classes as much as possible.

Basically I have a base class `BaseClass`, where two properties are referencing a a class that is Extending `BaseClass` => `ClassA`

It works if I remove ClassB.
It works if I remove one of the two references.
It works when I don't extend `ClassA` from the `BaseClass`

But not in this constellation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading;

namespace EFTestbed
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ClassA ClassA1 { get; set; }
        public ClassA ClassA2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassA : BaseClass
    {
        public string TitleA { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB : BaseClass
    {
        public string TitleB { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ClassA> ClassAs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.ClassA1).WithOptionalDependent();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.ClassA2).WithOptionalDependent();

            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.ClassA1).WithOptionalDependent();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.ClassA2).WithOptionalDependent();

        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Creating & Updating database...");

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.ClassAs.Add(new ClassA() { TitleA = "Test1" });
                System.Console.WriteLine(
                  string.Format("Number of objects written to the database: {0}", 
                                context.SaveChanges()));
            }

            System.Console.Write("Press Enter to continue...");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I always get this Exception *"Sequence contains more than one element"*

How do I get it to work?

Here is the stack trace of the Exception:

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureDependentBehavior(EdmAssociationType associationType, EdmModel model, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmNavigationProperty navigationProperty, EdmModel model, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureAssociations(EdmEntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EdmEntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntities(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at EFTestbed.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\users\sasp1de\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EFTestbed\EFTestbed\TestEF\Program.cs:line 54
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Can you post also the stack trace? And which line throws the exception?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me - if you are doing something wrong you should get a better exception. Would you mind reporting it here: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic?

Comment: Thanks. Created an issue. Please upvote if you have the same problem:
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in the latest version of EF:
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/546